# How can I load data before any components open in Svelte

Tags: javascript, frontend, svelte

I'm trying to use data attached to a userID key to load the correct data. This is stored in a Svelte store linked to a database which is read like `DATA[userID]["temp"]["Service_Scaling"][service][mode]`. However before I open the page my userID data might not be set up yet, and I'd like to run this function before anything else opens. How can I do this?

```
// Check if user exists and if not creates new user with temp data
export const identifyUser = (userID) => {
  // Set svelte userID store
  userIDstore.set(userID);

  let data = get(dataStore);
  let dataCopy;

  // Check if user exists
  if (Object.hasOwn(data, userID)){
    console.log("Identified user: "+userID)
  }
  // If new user create temp and defaults
  else {
    console.log("User: "+userID+" not recognised. New user created.")
    dataCopy = data['default_changing']
    let parsedCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(dataCopy))
    // create empty user object
    data[userID] = data[userID] || {};
    // populate with temp and defaults
    data[userID]["temp"] = parsedCopy;
    data[userID]["defaults"] = parsedCopy;
  }
  //update store
  dataStore.updateData(data);
}
```

I've read about using +page.js files but do they run before loading or just the same as it would be within a `<script>` tag. `onMount` doesn't work for me here as it loads the components first so crashes the page.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have happily answered my own question: put it all in a svelte load function inside of `+page.js` and it does all this!

```
export async function load ({params}) {
```

Does the trick.